# can not send mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a problem to send a mysql query where this problem :ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax appears, my code where user is an javascript object contains 3 strings username,email,password .

```
let sql2 = 'insert into users (username,email,password) values (' + user.username + ',' + user.email + ',' + user.password + ')'  //query

           
        db.query(sql2,(err,result) => {
                if(err) throw err 
                res.send('User registriation done')
        })
```

Comment: you need to use escaping arround every injected variable. use db.escape() for exemple.

Comment: Use parameters instead of concatenating variables.

Comment: @Barmar if i need to use this query how to write user.emailcorrect :  let sql = "select email from users where email =  " + user.email

Comment: `let sql = 'select email from users where email = ?'` and then pass `user.email` in the parameter arraay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not putting quotes around the string values. But the correct way is to use parameters rather than concatenating variables into the SQL.

```
let sql2 = 'insert into users (username,email,password) values (?, ?, ?)' //query
db.query(sql2, [user.username, user.email, user.password], (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err
  res.send('User registriation done')
})
```